# How do I fix my local repo so I can save work from commits that haven’t been pushed to the master git repo?

Tags: git, mercurial, git-rebase

I could probably find a way to do the following, but I’d prefer to do this the “correct” way.

Here is the output of branch and status:

```
docker@noakland:~/stacks$ git branch
* master
docker@noakland:~/stacks$

docker@noakland:~/stacks$ git status
On branch master
Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
and have 2 and 1 different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
docker@noakland:~/stacks$
```

git tree = git log --graph --decorate --pretty=format:'%C(bold yellow)%h %Cred%cr %C(bold blue)(%an)%C(bold cyan)%d%Creset %s' --abbrev-commit --all

git tree yields:

```
* f3d7b51 65 minutes ago (Mike) (HEAD -> master) feeder
* 12778e1 79 minutes ago (Mike) feeder test
| * d829803 3 days ago (Mike) (origin/master, origin/HEAD) tmp
|/  
* 7365aca 5 days ago (Mike) restore snapshot image
```

Commits `12778e1` and `f3d7b51` have **not** been pushed to the central repo.

I want to update to `d829803` and apply the changes in commits `12778e1` and `f3d7b51` as a *new* commit appearing on top of `d829803`. There are only 3 files I’m interested in keeping, so I’ll undo/revert changes to those files from `d829803`.

I *think* I want my tree to look something like this (Though not sure about the branch names)

```
 * abcdef9 10 seconds ago (Mike) (HEAD -> master) feeder
 * d829803 3 days ago (Mike) (origin/master, origin/HEAD) tmp
 * 7365aca 5 days ago (Mike) restore snapshot image
```

So how can I update to `d829803`, cherry-pick the changes from the un-pushed commits, manually revert changes to file `abc.txt` @ `d829803` and then get rid of `12778e1` and `f3d7b51` so they won’t get pushed to the master repo, nor exist in the local repo?

With hg this would be simple:

```
hg update d829803
hg revert -r 12778e1 —-all
hg revert -r f3d7b51 —-all
hg revert -r d829803 abc.txt
hg commit -m “manually cherry picked”
hg strip 12778e1
hg strip f3d7b51
hg push
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I'll give you the way I'd do it.
The operation you are willing to make is called a rebase, and it's very usefull in situations you need to rewrite history, specially when you want a branch to have it's origins changed.

For your operation, I'll give you a way to do that, but keep in mind that conflicts may happen on the way. More on that at the end.

I'll also assume you won't upload the new states of those branches until the end. That's helpfull because it's much simpler to do a git reset and start over than to fix the upstream repo.

1. First, understanding the state.
   Your initial state is:

- `master` pointing at `f3d7b51`
- `origin/master` pointing at `d829803`
- `d829803` serving as the root where both diverged. It's important to know the new root when moving branches here and there.

2. You wish, as I understood, to fuse `f3d7b51` and `12778e1` so they appear as a single commit. This operation is called a squash, inside the rebase. We'll this info in a bit.
3. To do the rebase, I'll recomend it's interactive version. At the terminal, do:

```sh
git checkout master
git rebase -i origin/master #this is commit d829803
```

Your terminal will open your text editor or ask you which one you want to use. This is a simple text editing we will be doing, so pick whatever you're confortable with.

Once the editor opens, It should show you a sequence of commits. proposed by the rebase operation. If nothing is altered, it's going to apply the changes on top of `d829803`, doing a new commit for each one. You really are moving the commits around, changing their parent commit with this.

Remember the squash? If my assumption is correct, you need to change the "command" beside the commit hash in this editing operation, replacing "pick" with "squash". This fuses both commits, as if they where a single one. The order of changes is also respected (if you don't move lines up and down)

So, your rebase should initially look like this:

```
pick 12778e1  feeder test
pick f3d7b51  feeder

# operation  hash  commit message
```

You can, then fuse the commits and even alter the message:

```
pick 12778e1  implement feeder
squash f3d7b51  feeder
```

This is what is going to happen when you save the file and exit editing:

- git will rewind and go to origin/master (aka d829803)
- the differente be presented at the editor, for you to edit the sequence, change message, squash, or even remove commits from history.
- when you save and exit, git will apply `12778e1` and then `f3d7b51`, at this order, creating a single commit with a different hash and the message `implement feeder`
- Your tree will look like this:

```
* ab46d2a 65 minutes ago (Mike) (HEAD -> master) implement feeder
|
* d829803 3 days ago (Mike) (origin/master, origin/HEAD) tmp
|  
* 7365aca 5 days ago (Mike) restore snapshot image
```

If you wish to remove `12778e1`, just remove it's line when editing.

### Conflicts

If you have a conflict, the operations will pause, git will warn you about the conflicted files.

In this scenario you can resolve them or abort. To abort simply use `git rebase --abord`.

Solving is merelly going to those files, merging them to get the changes you need from the conflicted commits, executing a git add and git commit. To continue the rebase, use `git rebase --continue`

### References

- https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing
- https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History